# In Unity3d, How do you add a floating window (such as lightmapping) to an existing set of tabs (ex: Inspector)?

Tags: user-interface, configuration, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

In Unity3d, on Mac, how do you add a spawned floating window (such as lightmapping) to an existing set of tabs (ex: Inspector) ?

I haven't found a way to do that... When I click on the Add Tab control on the upper right of the inspector, there is no option for Lightmapping. There must be a command, I have tried using alt, cmd, ctrl etc, to no avail..

Thanks !

Comment: nice question.. I guess you intend by script, because otherwise you can simply drag it. Maybe you can customize the context menu for a new entry in Add tab..but I don't know if there is any API that let you manage the layout by code.

Comment: I actually meant without scripting ;) but thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grab the floating window on its tab (where the window's name is), and just drag it near the tabs where you want it to dock. This works on both editor's and user's custom windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was trying on the rest of the bar, never on the window's name itself ;)